# Make both a string and an array of strings to a one-dimensional array of string in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

***Disclaimer:*** I feel like this might be read as a simple "how do I flatten an array" or "how to arrayify a string". It's not that type of question. (Now, I feel like someone should have asked that already despite the above but I haven't been lucky finding it.

In my code, I can receive a string with a message or an array of strings of with messages. It's a poor design that I can't alter. In order to present all the messages to the user (independent of whether it's a single one or a bunch), I'm doing the following.

```
let data = error.value;
if (typeof (data) === "string")
  data = [data];
data.forEach(_ => this.messages.push({ type: "danger", contents: _ }));
```

I feel inconvenient with this guard using if to check if it's not an array and make it so. I'd much more like to see something that makes a string to an array, makes an array to a matrix and then maps them onto a 1D-array (i.e. equilizing the dimensions).

How would I go about flattening an array **to X dimensional** (as opposed to flattening an array **by Y dimensions**?

Example:

> "poof" -> ["poof"]

while

> ["poof", "shake the", "roof"] -> ["poof", "shake the", "roof"]

Comment: "*makes an array to a matrix*": why would you want that? I don't see the need for the example you have given. There is no matrix involved.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: @trincot I can see how it's confusingly expressed. Please see my comment to the accepted answer. Perhaps it sheds some light on how I was figuring (not claiming it was a wise trail of thoughts, just how I viewed it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) and do something like this:

```
let data = Array.isArray(error.value) ? error.value : [ error.value ];
data.forEach(contents => this.messages.push({ type: "danger", contents }));
```

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit better, although still the conditional check of type. I was hoping for something where I **always** put brackets around the error and then remove all the brackets (dimensions) except for the last one. Perhaps I'm just unnecessarily complicating things. +1 for sample.